# In extjs when dragdrop 'offsetWidth' is null or not an object error for IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4.1

I am doing drag and drop to a panel, it is working fine in IE8, Chrome and Firefox, but for Ie7 i am getting this error -" 'offsetWidth' is null or not an object"

when i am debugging it is pointing to the following code,

```
    getLocation: function (i) {
        if (!this.isTypeOfDD(i))
        { return null }
        if (i.getRegion)
        { return i.getRegion() }
        var g = i.getEl(), m, d, c, o, n, p, a, k, h;
        try { m = Ext.Element.getXY(g) }
        catch (j) { }
        if (!m) { return null }
        d = m[0];
        c = d + g.offsetWidth;
        o = m[1];
        n = o + g.offsetHeight;
        p = o - i.padding[0];
        a = c + i.padding[1];
        k = n + i.padding[2];
        h = d - i.padding[3];
        return new Ext.util.Region(p, a, k, h)
    }
```

specifically to g.offsetWidth, where g is also undefined, and i is of type "Ext.dd.DropZone" and it occurs sometimes only. i am trying to odd it out. meantime if any one have some clues please share with me.
Advance Thanks

Comment: elements in dataview with XTemplate. actually solved this. updating with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this by adding a condition checking. it is working fine upto this time.

```
getLocation: function (i) {
    if (!this.isTypeOfDD(i))
    { return null }
    if (i.getRegion)
    { return i.getRegion() }
    var g = i.getEl(), m, d, c, o, n, p, a, k, h;
    if(g!=null){
    try { m = Ext.Element.getXY(g) }
    catch (j) { }
    if (!m) { return null }
    d = m[0];
    c = d + g.offsetWidth;
    o = m[1];
    n = o + g.offsetHeight;
    p = o - i.padding[0];
    a = c + i.padding[1];
    k = n + i.padding[2];
    h = d - i.padding[3];       
    return new Ext.util.Region(p, a, k, h)
    }
}
```

Comment: We came across an issue like this recently and modifying this method was not the right solution and thought I would share here as the real issue is probably elsewhere. The issue we had was that one of our drop zone or drag zone that was created and added to the group was not destroyed when the components it was created on were. So there were some zones still in the DragDropManager memory that should have been cleared. In some cases, when the internal refresh cache was done, it was breaking because those did not exist anymore. It was as simple as removing the zones from the groups on destroy.

Comment: spaque99 nailed it. In the elememt render I created a dragzone without destroying it on the beforedestroy. This gave the error as described. destroying the dragzone on the elements beforedestroy solved my problem